# Approximating $1_I$, $I\subset \lbrack 0,1\rbrack$, by trigonometric polynomials

Tags: fourier-analysis, exponential-sums, trigonometric-polynomials

Let $I$ be a subinterval of $\lbrack 0,1\rbrack$. How well can one hope to approximate it in the $L_1$-norm (on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$) by a trigonometric polynomial of degree $\leq R$, that is, a function

$$x\mapsto \sum_{r=-R}^R c_r e(r x),$$

where $e(t) = e^{2 \pi i t}$? Are substantially better approximations possible if we allow a linear combination of any $2 R + 1$ different exponentials $e(r x)$ (for not necessarily consecutive values of $r$)?

One can ask the same questions about the sawtooth function x\mapsto {x} instead of $1_{I}$; indeed the two settings feel equivalent.
(There are functions related to Beurling-Selberg majorant that may be useful to consider; I've taken a look again at the first chapter of Montgomery's Ten Lectures. It is still unclear to me whether such functions give something approximately optimal with respect to the $L^1$ norm.)

Comment: Well, by inclusion you can do at least as good  as $L^{2}$ approximation, but this you must already know. What are you hoping for? is your interval fixed? or are you looking for a set of $2R+1$ exponentials that would work for all intervals?  this question is a bit vague

Comment: Say the interval is fixed. Selberg's approximant gives us that we can come to within distance $1/R$ of $1_I$ by means of a trigonometric polynomial of degree $R$. Can one do much better? Can one replace $1/R$ by $1/R^2$, say?